# Postgresql Debugger on Windows

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I've seen the docs to install the debugger on linux machines. But no docs on how to install the debugger on a windows machine. Does anyone know how to do this? Looks like you have to compile the pldebugger somehow.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'd have to build the `pldebugger` extension.

Unfortunately, building PostgreSQL extensions on Windows is non-trivial: apart from the requirement of a C compiler, you have to come up with the correct compiler invocation, since the PostgreSQL extension building infrastructure does not work on Windows.

The PostgreSQL community is aware of that deficiency, but it is not easy to come up with solutions for a platform that is so different from all others.

Comment: Thanks you, this would explain why I could not get it figured out. Thanks again!

Comment: I ended up installing EDB Advanced Server. The debugger works, but now I have issues with retrieving dates using a client. But at least I'm able to debug.

Comment: Debugging may work, but now you are stuck with a closed source fork and have to pay license fees. I personally have never felt the need for a debugger, I make do with `RAISE NOTICE`. And I write a lot of PL/pgSQL.

Comment: You're crazy! :-). I was using raise notice, but I had so many notices put in, it became hard to read what was going on. I'm doing IOT stuff now, lots of signal processing, but if I was in insurance of medical billing I would without a doubt need a debugger. I am not a C guy, but if I were to build a debugger what would I need to read to build one? thanks

Answer (score 0):

`[Enterprisedb distribution][1]` of Postgre SQL includes Pgadmin and Postgres Debugger. The path to the debugger dll is: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\lib

You can find  installation notes C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\doc\installation-notes.html

Edit your postgresql.conf file, which is located in the default PostGreSql Data directory and modify the shared_preload_libraries config option to look like the following, if running on Linux or Mac: shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/plugin_debugger.so' or if you are on Windows: shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/plugin_debugger.dll'

Restart PostgreSQL for the new setting to take effect.

To install an extension in a particular database, you need to either use the CREATE EXTENSION command in that database, or use PgAdmin 4's interface to install it.

Command method: Through whichever tool you wish, where you enter regular SQL commands, connect to the relevant database in question and run:

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pldbgapi;

GUI method: In PgAdmin 4, open up the nodes for the database you want to install this extension for, right-click on "Extensions", then select Create > Extension... Now select pldbgapi from the drop-down list next to "Name" and click "Save".

You will need to repeat this process if you need the extension in additional databases within your cluster.

If you got the following error:

ERROR: Installing the extension "pldbgapi" failed, because it is not on the list of extensions supported by Azure Database for PostgreSQL. extension "pldbgapi" is not supported by Azure Database for PostgreSQL ERROR: extension "pldbgapi" is not supported by Azure Database for PostgreSQL SQL state: 0A000 Detail: Installing the extension "pldbgapi" failed, because it is not on the list of extensions supported by Azure Database for PostgreSQL. Hint: To see the full list of supported extensions run: SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions;

Go into the Server Configuration on the Tools menu and enable shared_preload_libraries item by checking the checkbox next to it. Editing the configuration file and bouncing the database server alone don't enable the debugger in the database.

Reference:

[Using PgAdmin PLPgSQL Debugger - Postgres OnLine Journal](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/214-Using-PgAdmin-PLPgSQL-Debugger.html)